# Image URL is being saved into database but image is not saved in designated folder in VS2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

> The given path's format is not supported.

Tried using Path.Combine, removed '~' from path but image still doesn't save in "Images" folder.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PropertyViewModel propertyViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Property property = new Property();
        property.Id = propertyViewModel.Id ?? 0;
        property.PropertyCost = propertyViewModel.PropertyCost;
        property.PropertyDescription = propertyViewModel.PropertyDescription;
        HttpPostedFileBase fup = Request.Files["PropertyImage"];
        if(fup!=null)
        {
            property.PropertyImage = fup.FileName;
            fup.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fup.FileName));

            //string path = "~/Images/"+fup.FileName;
            ////string combinedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path,fup.FileName);
            //fup.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
        }
        _propertyQueryProcessor.Create(property);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fup.FileName`?

Comment: And not related, but since you using a view model it should contain property `HttpPostedFileBase PropertyImage` so its bound to your model

Comment: ViewModel has an attribute public string PropertyImage

Comment: Why (its should be `HttpPostedFileBase` - its your `Property` model that shoukd contain that, not the view model). But you still have not answered my question

Comment: I meant the entity model also has that attribute. and About the value of server.mappath, I dont understand what that means.Help!

Comment: `string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fup.FileName;` - what does that return?

Comment: I feel like a Dummy as i have no idea how to reply to You.I think I should delete the question. :|

Comment: Just add the above line of code as the first line in the `if(fup!=null) {` and put a breakpoint on it and check what the value of `path` is

Comment: if(fup!=null) {string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fup.FileName); property.PropertyImage = fup.FileName;}  Path is null and shows the same format not supported exception.

Comment: Use `var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), fup.FileName); fup.SaveAs(path);`

Comment: While using var path, it is returning "C:\\Users\\Sudeep Shrestha\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\dgds.png" which is the designated file but this file is still not being saved in the Projects Images folder.No exception is being thrown.

Comment: It cannot possible return that (it would at least include the `Images` folder in the path)

Comment: It is returning the complete path from where the image is to be uploaded.It is throwing no exception.There is no sign of 'Images' anywhere.

Comment: In the UI index page where the image thumbnail should be there is just a cross :/

Comment: I really want to solve this. :| The tutorial I watched did the same thing with no error but its not working on me or my friends laptops.

Comment: But if i Use:-----string path = "~/Images/" + fup.FileName;
                    string combinedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fup.FileName);
                    fup.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(combinedPath));
I get the foloowing exception:----
'C:/Users/Sudeep Shrestha/Pictures/Screenshots/dgds.png' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Comment: Could it be because of write access??

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now :)

**string filename = Server.MapPath("~" + "\\Images\\" + Path.GetFileName(fup.FileName));
                    fup.SaveAs(filename);**

The above code worked for me after including those double backslashes. :)